# Updating checkbox's checked status from parent - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I'm trying to create a reusable switcher component whose state won't be changed immediately when clicked, but after an API call is made in parent component - if there is no error, the state will be changed, while when there is an error, the state will remain unchanged.

The problem occurs when the checkbox state is updated from the parent level, the @Input value is updated correctly, but the checkbox state remains unchanged.

Simple reproduction of the problem at the link below:
[stackblitz-checkbox-issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v95bdk?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

I tried to use ChangeDetectorRef after updating the @Input value, ngModel bindinig, but to no avail.

Any ideas what to do to update the checkbox state from the parent level to work properly?

Comment: never listen to `click` event on an input. You have to listen to the `change` event or similar. The best practice is to use `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`. Also, there is only the child component (checkbox) in the stackblitz, so we cannot reproduce your issue...

Comment: oh, my bad, your parent component is in the main.ts... -_-

Comment: @Random - yes, I quickly made a parent component in the main.ts file. I am listening to the `click` event to block the automatic change of the checkbox state, inside `(ngModelChange)` it is too late for that, because then the checkbox state has already been changed, and after checkbox click I want to make an API call in the parent component and change checkbox's state based on the response from API. Maybe you have an idea how to do it in another way, I will be grateful for any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, the `preventDefault` is indeed messings things up. I would suggest not to use a checkbox, but a custom component instead. Replace the checkbox with an icon, and change state of the icon manually. No inputs.

Comment: that's actually a good idea, because `preventDefault` really messings things up. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works if you change the value of checked under the subscribe to the API, To simulate you can declare an object or a service

```
export const service:any={
  getData:()=>of(Math.random()>.5?true:false).pipe(delay(500))
}
```

And use some like, e.g.

```
  //main.ts
  toggleSwitcher(e: boolean) {
    service.getData().subscribe((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res)
      if (res)
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    })
  }
```

I [forked your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zparye?file=src%2Fswitcher%2Fswitcher.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fswitcher%2Fswitcher.component.html)

NOTE: You can also force to redraw the app

```
toggleSwitcher(e: boolean) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    })
}
```

Comment: real hero, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are in a complicated way...
You need to know all about angular tools...
You need to split the functionality and set in the rigth place...

So...

Your checkbox component must be reponsable for api call and then propagate the response for all components of your application...

If your component has childen the use @Input un your children.
If your component has parent use EventEmitter in simple way
If your component has parents, children, brothers compontens, use  Suject/Behavior-Subject

Try to do something like this, you will gain maintaining, time, readability, good practice, ease communication, and save cost:

```
export class SwitcherComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isChecked: boolean = false;

  constructor() // you need inject your service here
  {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSwitcherClick(e: any) {
    console.log('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    service.getData().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res) this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        // this.toggleSwitcher.emit(this.isChecked); // <= Dont use this aproach any more
        // you need create a subject comunication services for propagate to all components the response, 
      }
    );
  }
}
```